# Does Blindsight detect a scrying sensor?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, special-senses

My party's going to be encountering an [Elder Oblex](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/elder-oblex) that's gained more sentience than usual. The party has a mirror of Scrying (cast once per day without components/slots). They're wanting to use said mirror to spy on the Oblex, get an idea where exactly it is, plan an ambush for it.

Elder Oblex has blindsight. Assuming the Oblex fails the save to resist the *[Scrying](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/scrying)* spell, would it notice the sensor created by the spell? The sensor is invisible, which would be ignored by the blindsight, but I'm not sure if the sensor does any other kind of sensory effect that could be detectable by blindsight.

The exact wording of *Scrying* is:

> On a failed save, the spell creates an invisible sensor within 10 feet of the target. You can see and hear through the sensor as if you were there. The sensor moves with the target, remaining within 10 feet of it for the duration. A creature that can see invisible objects sees the sensor as a luminous orb about the size of your fist.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Answer (score 8):

### Blindsight can detect invisible objects.

> A creature that can see invisible objects sees the sensor

Implies that this sensor is an object or at least treated like an object for the matter of perception.

Blindsight (PHB 183):

> can perceive its surroundings without relying on sight

Blindsight doesn't inform the creature about the nature of the spell. It merely detects that there is an object. As a special sense Blindsight bypasses the mechanics of being [invisible](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Invisible), the condition states (my emphasis):

> An invisible creature is impossible to see without the aid of magic or a **special sense**.

Blindsight is a special type of [sense](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/monsters#Senses), and while the sensor is no creature, the logic applies to objects as well.

Answer (score 4):

## Would Blindsight see it? Well, maybe.

The description of the spell simply says the sensor is invisible.
Invisible objects still have mass, physical dimensions and the like. If other properties were to be applied, terms like 'intangible', 'ethereal', etc would have been used. So it is just invisible going  by Rules As Written.

The sensor is merely described as:

> A creature that can see invisible objects sees the sensor as **a luminous orb about the size of your fist**.

Going by that description it gives off no sound or smell or other detectable evidence of its presence beyond being a glowing ball if it can be viewed.

This part - "A creature that can see invisible objects sees the sensor" - also gives us a slight preference for claiming the scrying sensor is actually an object, but it isn't a water tight argument.

Blindsight is described as:

> A creature with blindsight can perceive its surroundings without relying on sight, within a specific radius. Creatures without eyes, such as oozes, and creatures with echolocation or heightened senses, such as bats and true dragons, have this sense.

So it would seem that the type of blindsight is important. Echolocation would detect the sensor's presence (as it has a physical manifestation) but, as worded, heightened senses would not unless you decide the sensor does give off some form clue to its presence that could be detected by Blindsight.

So, what would Blindsight actually mean for an Elder Oblex? Going by the stat block of the Oblex I would say not. It has no abilities to suggest it could detect a silent, hovering, invisible ball

Comment: You are equating this to a spell effect that says nothing about creation of an object?

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to express with that comment. If you have an issue with the steps in my analysis please be more specific, I'd be happy to hear your thoughts.

Comment: Do we have any indication that it has a physical manifestation? The wording only suggests a visible manifestation. The orb doesn’t seem to be affected by physical barriers otherwise it would have a hard time following a creature that goes through doors. I’m not sure Echolocation would find this.

Comment: As I said in my answer "If other properties were to be applied, terms like 'intangible', 'ethereal', etc would have been used." Spells do what they say they do and this spell creates an invisible object. "The orb doesn’t seem to be affected by physical barriers otherwise it would have a hard time following a creature that goes through doors." - that's you implying abilities to the sensor that aren't mentioned in the spell.

Comment: That is exactly my point. You are indicating that because it doesn't say intangible that it isn't. It doesn't say that it creates an object it is merely a spell effect. Can blindsight detect Mage Hand or Scorching Ray or Minor Illusion or Unseen Servant etc.? I am merely leaning the other way on the interpretation so as to say: It doesn't say it conjures an object therefore it doesn't. Also the fact that it is Divination and not Conjuration helps (although I am in the minority on making schools matter).

Comment: "A creature that can see invisible OBJECTS sees the sensor" - not a kill shot as to the nature of the sensor but it adds more weight to the physical side of the argument.

Comment: @Slagmoth it sounds like that you should write your answer arguing that the sensor is a magical effect and that the twisting and weaving of magical effects is imperceptible by blindsight.