# Can a creature with Blindsight see a Scrying Sensor? Is that sensor an object? Can it be destroyed?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic, divination, special-senses

[Scrying](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Scrying#content):

> A creature that can see Invisible Objects sees the sensor as a luminous orb about the size of your fist.

[Blind Sight](https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/5e_SRD:Blindsight):

> A creature with blindsight can perceive its surroundings without relying on sight, within a specific radius. Creatures without eyes, such as oozes, and creatures with echolocation or heightened senses, such as bats and true dragons, have this sense.

Comment: Duplicate on the first question: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/165850/62294

Comment: Duplicate on the third question: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/169791/62294

Comment: Unless you’re really interested in the second question, we can close this as a duplicate. I would recommend searching around the site, at least a little bit, before posting questions. Searching “scrying blindsight” turned up that first link as the first result.

Comment: One question per question please. These are three, that don't follow from one another.